# Prettyfaces link with user input as parameter

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

I got following code in my xhtml:

```
<h:inputText binding="#{year}" />
<h:inputText binding="#{month}" />

<pretty:link value="Create" mappingId="pretty:addEntity">
    <f:param name="year" value="#{year.value}" />
    <f:param name="month" value="#{month.value}" />
    Create Entity
</pretty:link>
```

Also I got a bean with an `init` method anotated with `@URLAction(onPostback = false)`.

I want to read the passed parameter in this method. The params are not in the request parameter map of JSF nor part of the query string (`com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance().getRequestQueryString()`)

How can I pass those parameter to the init method without binding them to a backing bean?

```
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLAction;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping;

import de.financeme.view.menu.NaviCase;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@URLMapping(id = "addEntity", pattern = "/entity/add", viewId = "/entity/add.xhtml")
public class Bean {

  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String month;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  private int year;

  @URLAction(onPostback = false)
  public void init() {
    // month = null
    // year = 0
  }
}
```

Even with binding them to the backing bean. I am not calling any submit function. So they won't get stored into their respective fields.

What is wrong? What am I missing here?

Comment: Please include the code of your bean and the mappings.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Is that enough information?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the parameters to your bean in your pattern. Something like this:

```
<pretty:link value="Create" mappingId="pretty:addEntity">
    <f:param name="year" value="2017" />
    <f:param name="month" value="12" />
    Create Entity
</pretty:link>
```

And the bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@URLMapping(id = "addEntity", 
    pattern = "/entity/#{bean.year}/#{bean.month}/add", 
    viewId = "/entity/add.xhtml")
public class Bean {

  // ...

}
```

Now you will get links like this:

`/entity/2017/12/add`

Comment: How would you handle user input? Basically, I want the user to fill in month and year and then the user get redirected to the `addEntity` page by clicking on the `pretty:link`.